# How and when is a JCo connection closed in version 3.xx?

Tags: java, jco

In older versions of JCo (2.xx), the connections were handled directly: the developer needed to create the connection and then close it. It was intuitive.

With the newer versions there's no closing connection method, just `getDestination` methods.

I was wondering: how and when is an established connection closed?

SCN: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3770683